# PuTTy connecting to server from one machine and not from another

Tags: ssh, ftp, putty, winscp

I am trying to connect to a server(linux) via SSH from a windows m/c via putty.

I can connect to the server from my m/c using putty but when i try to do the same from another machine, i get an error.

All configs are the same. Can you please give some pointers as to what might be the issue.

**Note:** I am able to do an FTP(port 21) to the same server via WinSCP on both machines. It's just putty which is not doing SSH on the other m/c. It's fine on my m/c.

Any directions would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you log in with WinSCP via SFTP/SCP? If not, then the server might be firewalled against that other machine. Or maybe the two machines are connected to the server with different interfaces and SSH is configured to only listen to one of them. Check the firewall on the server and, for good measure, the firewall on your client.

Comment: Yes, I can login via WinSCP using just `FTP`. How do i check that the server is listening to only one of the m/c's. Can you please tell. Thanks.

Comment: No I meant with *SFTP* or *SCP*. I'm asking because those use the same port and protocol as SSH, whereas FTP does not. As for finding out whether it's only listening on one network card/IP, you could run netstat -a on the server and check for lines with ':ssh' and LISTEN at the end. If there's one that reads '0.0.0.0:ssh', then it ain't that.

Comment: Oh, in WinSCP, when i use `SFTP`, i am able to connect on 1 m/c but not on the other one. That's the issue. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Well, sounds like it's a firewall thing then. Check the firewalls on your clients and try iptables -L on the server. That and the netstat thing from above.